# Submitting an action to Open Graph doesn't work - any way around it?

Tags: submit, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to submit an Open Graph action, but the submission process gets stuck after the second stage - pressing "continue" grays out the fields, but they pop right back into being enabled and there's no transition to the final step, just a loading indication near the "continue" button.

Seems the bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/319383498127002) is reproducible, but I'm wondering if this might be something specific to my account, or anything similar.

Ideas on how to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple bugs open on this, but it looks like no one is in a hurry to solve it. Is this a system wide problem? 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/319383498127002
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/113025105498047
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/258992780854438
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/201699046610161
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/388339414521584
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/263464827073477

Answer (score 2):

until the bug gets fixed, try using https://developers.beta.facebook.com. The bug maybe fixed in that version of Facebook.